# Squiggles for C++ in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, plugins, syntax-error

Is there a plugin for Visual Studio 2008 that can show **squiggles** for C++ code (like in VS2010+)?

(I seem to recall that the excellent Visual Assist X plugin gives syntax highlighting, but doesn't squiggle incorrect C++ code.)

---

**EDIT**

Just to be clearer (since it was also asked in the comments), the requirement is not only about [*"mistyped symbols"*](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-code-correction.asp#under), but also about more advanced error checking.
e.g. if a class `X` has a *private* copy constructor, VS2010 correctly *squiggles* code like `X x1(x);` (with the addition of a nice error message):

[image]

Comment: Please add your definition of squiggle to your post.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I wrote in my post _"like in VS2010+"_, so I mean the squiggle experience offered by VS2010 and next. Anyway, I've edited my post, adding an example.

Comment: I'm curious why this question was downvoted. Those who downvote should at least leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: Balance restored. I remember I only used VS2010 because of this one feature back in the day, it was such a huge improvement - but hated many of the other changes, including insane disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

The newest Visual Assist X does have support for this feature (it's referred to as 'underlines' in the settings). It will also underline grammar and spelling mistakes, which Visual Studio 2010 by default doesn't do.
On a different note, you probably shouldn't be using Visual Studio 2008 as it is really really outdated (6+ years old), Visual Studio 2013, 2012 and 2010 all run much faster and have a much larger featureset.

http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-code-correction.asp#under

Comment: The [link you posted](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-code-correction.asp#under) is about _"mistyped symbols"_. But VS2010+ can do better (see the example I added). _On a different note_, there are still some projects and quality software written with VS2008 (e.g. VMware Workstation, or Dropbox, as the date of writing). Read also [this interview by Mike Dunn](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319923/A-Coder-Interview-With-Michael-Dunn). Anyway, I do enjoy the new C++11 features and STL improvements available in VS2010, but that is not the point of the question.

Comment: Fair enough. Although really people ought to be using build control systems like CMake, which are also crossplatform. :)

Comment: Will have to disagree on VS2010+ being faster than VS2008 - the latter is insanely fast in comparison to the others if you ever still find a reason to use it! I have it as the default editor for header + source files, for quick viewing; VS2013 would take about 2x as long just to startup :)